# Looking for Domino XSL help trying to find fields where the color is set to Blue

Tags: xslt, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a very large form with hundreds of fields on it.  Some are black and some are blue.  I'm trying to parse the dxl using xsl to find the fields where they are set to the color blue.

i've found several xsl files to parse the dxl but I can'tfigure out how to find the field then find the previous font color='blue'

Can anyone help me with that syntax?  Here is a sample of the dxl I am trying to parse:

```
 <par def="100">
   <run>
      <font size="9pt" style="bold" name="Arial" pitch="variable" truetype="true" familyid="20" />
   </run>
   <run>
      <font size="9pt" color="blue" style="bold" name="Arial" pitch="variable" truetype="true" familyid="20" />
      <field type="text" kind="editable" name="DevComments">
         <code event="inputtranslation">
            <formula>@Trim( @ThisValue )</formula>
         </code>
      </field>
   </run>
   <compositedata type="98" prevtype="65418" nexttype="222" afterparcount="6" containertype="65418" aftercontainercount="1" afterbegincount="3">Yg4BAIQAAAAAAAAAAAA=</compositedata>
   <run>
      <font size="9pt" style="bold" name="Arial" pitch="variable" truetype="true" familyid="20" />
   </run>
</par>
```

Comment: Where is your tried XSL ? show us to help you.

Comment: You could potentially do `//field[preceding-sibling::font[1]/@color='blue']` in this case, although I am not sure that is sufficient for all cases.

Comment: I don't think an XSLT would be able to acheive your desired outcome.  I would try a script routine that hunts through the .dxl text for <font  then finds color="blue" to turn on reporting.  Report all <field until there's another <font with attribute color where the value is not "blue".  Keep looping through the text until eof.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  That's what I ended up doing.